# How to understand convolution model

Tags: keras

This is my first time using keras.sequential to create a convolution model. Below is the code, and I don't understand what does the summary part means.

```
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dense, Dropout

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras import optimizers

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(16, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', 
                 input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))


model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer=optimizers.RMSprop(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 148, 148, 16)      448       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 74, 74, 16)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 72, 72, 64)        9280      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 36, 36, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 34, 34, 128)       73856     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2 (None, 17, 17, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 36992)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 512)               18940416  
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 513       
=================================================================
Total params: 19,024,513
Trainable params: 19,024,513
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model.summary() gives you information about the output shape and number of parameters for each layer of your model.  For example, the first layer "conv2d_1" corresponds the the first layer in your python code

```
model.add(Conv2D(16, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', 
                 input_shape=input_shape))
```

It tells you that the output from that layer has shape (None, 148, 148, 16).  The "None" refers the the sample/batch dimension, which normally is not specified in Keras models.  It gets automatically inferred from the actual input data.  The rest of the shape says you have 148x148x16 data, which you can think of as a stack of 16 images of 148x148.  The "16" comes from the first argument in the

```
Conv2D(16,...
```

The parameters are the number of weights in the layer, which I believe are all trainable.  This tells you something about the complexity of the model and how long it will take to train in a relative way - More parameters, more processing etc...

The rest of the lines have a similar analysis.  I hope this helps.